# Grafana: Simple json data source implementation

Tags: python, grafana

Has anyone written a json data source for grafana in python? I'm struggling with writing functions and understanding the flow.

I am looking for something like this - https://github.com/bergquist/fake-simple-json-datasource/blob/master/index.js but in python.

Answer (score 6):

I've just uploaded a snippet from our python datasource for grafana, it uses `pandas` + `flask` and very easy to extend.

https://gist.github.com/linar-jether/95ff412f9d19fdf5e51293eb0c09b850

Comment: please include the relevant change in your answer, state what you changed and why.

Comment: Not sure if the code need update or anything, I tried your code on github but /search / does not work at all.

Comment: @chandank Just tested with versions 1.3.1 and newer, and working fine, what is your setup? and if you can post the requests/responses received by the datasource

Answer (score 1):

To understand the flow, try looking at the generic implementation ...
https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource